# SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I'm creating a `SharedPreferences` and it's working only if I start Activity like this:

```
myIntent.putExtra("prefName", MYPREFS);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

But my SharedPreferences is not working after I save it and hit back a few times, to go at menu page and go to the page where I want to get my preferences.

Anyone can help me with that?

Code below:

This is where I save my preferences:

```
String MYPREFS = "MyPref";
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS,0);
myEditor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
```

Inside button onClickListener:

```
 myEditor.putString("address", AddressET.getText().toString());
    myEditor.putString("contact", ContactET.getText().toString());
    myEditor.commit();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(myContext, nok_individual_particular.class);
myIntent.putExtra("prefName", MYPREFS);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

---

This is the activity I pass to:

```
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
Intent myReceivingIntent = getIntent();
String myPREFName = myReceivingIntent.getStringExtra("prefName");

mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(myPREFName, 0);

applySavedPreferences();
```

In the applySavedPreferences method:

```
 String addressValue = mySharedPreferences.getString("address", "Jack Smith");
String contactValue = mySharedPreferences.getString("contact", "Jack Smith");   

addressTV.setText(addressValue);
contactTV.setText(contactValue);
```

Comment: Show us some code where u are saving and committing to the sharedprefereces file.

Comment: are you putting the a sharedpreference instance inside an intent?

Answer (score 3):

SharedPreferences: This is how it works

**To save your data**:

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefsName", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("valueName", "value");
editor.commit();
```

**To retrieve your data:**

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefsName", 0);
String strMyData = sPrefs.getString("valueName", "default value");
```

The example above is how to set a string and retrieve it.

Comment: Why are you passing your prefsName through intents? Just declared it somewhere like this: public static final String prefName = "name"; and access it from every activity you'd like to.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `SharedPreferences`. In your example, you are passing an extra to an activity, but this only makes available the value to the new activity, it doesn't save the value to `SharedPreferences`.

To use `SharedPreferences`, you have to do the following:

### Save

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("prefName", "String to save").commit();
```

### Get

```
String value = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("prefName"), "default value");
```

Answer (score 0):

After `mySharedPreferences.edit();`

```
mySharedPreferences.commit();
```

should be your last line. This enables u to save and close the SharedPreferences file you have edited.

Well, you don't need to pass the sharedprefs in an intent and all. It will be available throughout your application in all activities.

Just call `SharedPreferences my_prefs= getSharedPreferences("Pref_name", 0);` and then u have a reference to that SharedPreferences file and then u can retrieve values from it.

Comment: right now i can use my sharedPreferences straight from start actvity. But what i want is to go back to menu and go to the pages and it will display the Activity that i want to get sharePreference

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using SharedPreferences to save my data and use it throughout my classes , plus they will be saved to the device , making them available even after the app is killed ... Here is an example for ya !

```
//Some String that I should remember, I am just using the package name for now
String app = this.getPackageName();/*This is going to be used more like a file to save my stuff to*/
//Setting our sharedpreferences
SharedPreferences sha = sha = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(app, SherlockActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);


String myString = "This is the String that you want to save so you can use among your classes"

//Now we call in an editor for that SharedPreferences so we can write and delete stuff from it .

Editor edit = sha.edit();

//Now we insert our String.
edit.putString("Something_you_can_remember" , myString);//You will need the "Something_you_can_remember" a few lines ahead , so remember it !
edit.apply(); //Or we can use edit.commit() , but I prefer apply()

//Now our String is saved ! So lets read it !

String whatever = sha.getString("Something_you_can_remember" , "The String incase myString didn't even exist , saves you from a NullPointerException");

//Here we go ! Now we have our String saved and can be readable among the classes !
//Also , if you wanted to delete that String or whatever you "put" in there , you can call

edit.remove("Something_you_can_remember"); //or edit.clear() to remove all the values stored !
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

**Save**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
 sedt.putString("valueName", "String to save");
 sedt.commit();
```

**Get**

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 String valueName = sp.getString("valueName","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass SharedPrefences through intents, as SharedPreferences are available to the whole application and any activity has access to it.

You can refer to below example:

Either create SharedPreferences by giving them your choice of name:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

OR use default SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Use your preference file anywhere in your code by getting them through any of the above methods. No need to pass to different activities.

Once you call any of the above method, if the preference file of that name does not exist for your application, android will create one for you.